# In Google Analytics, how can I add the page where an event happened to a custom report?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, page

I'd like to add the page where an event was triggered to a custom report in Google Analytics.

I can see that the information is being sent to Google with the event, but when I select "Page" as a dimension nothing displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom report dimensions: Page, Event Category

And then filter the report for the particular event you want to check.

I have attached an image as an example[image]